# Workbox injectManifest as Azure devOps pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, service-worker, workbox

I want to include *workbox injectManifest* as a task in Azure DevOps pipeline, but seems like the Agent doesn't recognize workbox commands. Agent is self-hosted on Windows Server 2019. I was using *npm* task, then *Command line* task - both giving the same error result.

The command I want to run is:

```
workbox injectManifest "./src/workbox/workbox-config.js"
```

And here is the output (from *npm* task with *custom* command): [npm task in pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfz0C.jpg)

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
8.5.0 C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list" ; "builtin" config from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc

prefix = "C:\\Users\\serviceAccount_1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" 

; "env" config from environment

userconfig = "C:\\Build\\Agent_1\\_work\\6\\npm\\814.npmrc" 

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ; 
cwd = C:\Build\Agent_1\_work\6\s\Project ; 
HOME = C:\Users\serviceAccount_1 ;
 Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults. C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C 
""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" workbox injectManifest ./src/workbox/workbox-config.js" 
Unknown command: "workbox"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:   npm help
##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1 Finishing: npm workbox
```

workbox-cli is installed globally and also locally included in package.json, and workbox commands are recognized when I run them manually, directly on the server.
Problem occurs only when it's run by pipeline task.

So now, I wonder why *workbox* is not recognized by tasks, and what task should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If the **workbox-cli** was installed after the self-hosted agent, ensure you have restarted the agent service or directly restart the agent machine.

Normally, after installing the self-hosted agent, if you update or install some software / tools, you need to restart the agent service or the agent machine so that the software / tools can be available for the agent.

Once the software / tools are available for the agent, they generally would be listed as the capabilities of the agent.

Comment: Hi @PabloK, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer? Are the suggestions in my answer helpful for you?
As suggested in my answer, after installing the workbox-cli, you need to restart the agent service or the agent machine so that the software / tools can be available for the agent.

Comment: Hi, I've restarted both agent service and agent machine, but workbox-cli still was not available when running the pipeline. As a workaround, I wrapped workbox commands in a standalone script located on agent machine, then run the script as one of the pipeline tasks. It works, but I'm not happy with this solution tbh